# Keep receiving Too many indices for array for interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, debugging, error-handling

## interp - Program to interpolate data using Lagrange

I am not able to complete the for-loop in the coding sequence below. I don't see anything wrong with it, since I choose np.empty(nplot) to create the 1D array for xi, and for some reason the loop won't fill those values.

```
def intrpf(xi,x,y):
    """Function to interpolate between data points
       using Lagrange polynomial (quadratic)
       Inputs
        x    Vector of x coordinates of data points (3 values)
        y    Vector of y coordinates of data points (3 values)
        xi   The x value where interpolation is computed
      Output
        yi   The interpolation polynomial evaluated at xi
    """

#* Calculate yi = p(xi) using Lagrange polynomial
    yi = ( (xi-x[1])*(xi-x[2])/((x[0]-x[1])*(x[0]-x[2])) * y[0]
    + (xi-x[0])*(xi-x[2])/((x[1]-x[0])*(x[1]-x[2])) * y[1]
    + (xi-x[0])*(xi-x[1])/((x[2]-x[0])*(x[2]-x[1])) * y[2] )
    return yi

#* Initialize the data points to be fit by quadratic
x = np.empty(3)
y = np.empty(3)
print ('Enter data points as x,y pairs (e.g., [1, 2]')
for i in range(3):
    temp = np.array(input('Enter data point: '))
    x[i] = temp[0]
    y[i] = temp[1]

#* Establish the range of interpolation (from x_min to x_max)
xr = np.array(input('Enter range of x values as [x_min, x_max]: '))
```

**I'm getting stuck on this part, where it seems properly set up, but "Too many indices for array" appears on xi[i] within the for loop.**

```
#* Find yi for the desired interpolation values xi using
#  the function intrpf
nplot = 100     # Number of points for interpolation curve
xi = np.empty(nplot)
yi = np.empty(nplot)
for i in range(nplot) :
    xi[i] = xr[0] + (xr[1]-xr[0])* i/float(nplot)
    yi[i] = intrpf(xi[i], x, y)    # Use intrpf function to interpolate
```

Comment: show the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `np.array`:

> Parameters:
>
> object: _array_like_
>
> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose **array** method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.

This means array should receive something like a list, in order to make the casting, while input returns a string. What python is trying to do here at the end of the day is something like

```
np.array('[1, 2]')
```

While it might be tempting to do something like

```
np.array(eval(input()))
```

you should never do this because it is unsafe as it allows the user to execute any kind of code in your program. If you really need that kind of input I would suggest something like

```
np.array(list(map(int, input('Enter data point: ')
                       .replace('[','')
                       .replace(']','')
                       .split(','))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs with your data `input` lines:

```
Enter data points as x,y pairs (e.g., [1, 2]
Enter data point: [1,2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8d648ad8c9e4> in <module>
     22 for i in range(3):
     23     temp = np.array(input('Enter data point: '))
---> 24     x[i] = temp[0]
     25     y[i] = temp[1]
     26 

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

The code doesn't even get to  " I choose np.empty(nplot) to create the 1D array for xi, and for some reason the loop won't fill those values." part.

When asking for help, give full and accurate information about the error.

If I change the input lines to:

```
   ...: x = np.empty(3) 
   ...: y = np.empty(3) 
   ...: print ('Enter data points as x,y pairs') 
   ...: for i in range(3): 
   ...:     temp = input('Enter data point: ').split() 
   ...:     x[i] = temp[0] 
   ...:     y[i] = temp[1] 
   ...:  
   ...: #* Establish the range of interpolation (from x_min to x_max) 
   ...: xr = np.array(input('Enter range of x values as x_min, x_max: ').split(),float)                         
Enter data points as x,y pairs
Enter data point: 1 2
Enter data point: 3 4
Enter data point: 5 6
Enter range of x values as x_min, x_max: 0 4
In [9]: x                                                                                                       
Out[9]: array([1., 3., 5.])
In [10]: y                                                                                                      
Out[10]: array([2., 4., 6.])
In [11]: xr                                                                                                     
Out[11]: array([0., 4.])
```

Getting array values via user `input` is not ideal, but this at least works.  `input` (in Py3) does not evaluate the inputs; it just returns a string.  I split it (on default space), and then assign the values to an array.  `x` is defined as a float array, so the `x[i]=temp[0]` takes care of converting the string to float.  Similarly the `xr` line makes a float array from the string inputs.  This input style is not very robust; I could easily raise an error with wrong input.

===

The rest of the code runs with this input:

```
In [12]: nplot = 100     # Number of points for interpolation curve 
    ...: xi = np.empty(nplot) 
    ...: yi = np.empty(nplot) 
    ...: for i in range(nplot) : 
    ...:     xi[i] = xr[0] + (xr[1]-xr[0])* i/float(nplot) 
    ...:     yi[i] = intrpf(xi[i], x, y)    # Use intrpf function to interpolate 
    ...:                                                                                                        
In [13]: xi                                                                                                     
Out[13]: 
array([0.  , 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2 , 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 0.36, 0.4 ,
       0.44, 0.48, 0.52, 0.56, 0.6 , 0.64, 0.68, 0.72, 0.76, 0.8 , 0.84,
       ...
       3.52, 3.56, 3.6 , 3.64, 3.68, 3.72, 3.76, 3.8 , 3.84, 3.88, 3.92,
       3.96])
In [14]: yi                                                                                                     
Out[14]: 
array([1.  , 1.04, 1.08, 1.12, 1.16, 1.2 , 1.24, 1.28, 1.32, 1.36, 1.4 ,
       1.44, 1.48, 1.52, 1.56, 1.6 , 1.64, 1.68, 1.72, 1.76, 1.8 , 1.84,
       ....
       4.52, 4.56, 4.6 , 4.64, 4.68, 4.72, 4.76, 4.8 , 4.84, 4.88, 4.92,
       4.96])
```